# Cocoa - Errors with XML

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa

I am having some problems with XML writing to a file.  I am trying to create a tree with some elements in it, however the errors that I am getting are quite baffling, at least to me.

Below is an image of the errors that I am getting.. Can anyone shed some lights on them?

[image: xml errors]

Not sure if the image will be displayed large enough.. if not here is the link to the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zrt1.png

Apart from the last one (I have not declared anything to be returned), what is the problem with the other errors and warning?

Here is the code in text:

```
-(NSData *)constructXMLRequest
{   
    NSXMLElement *root = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"items"];

    NSXMLElement *item0 = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"item"];

        [item0 addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"0"]];

     NSXMLElement *object = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"object"];
     [object setStringValue:@"object 1"];
     NSXMLElement *description [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"description"];
     [object setStringValue:@"description 1"];

     [item0 addChild:object];
     [item0 addChild:description];

     [root addChild:item0];
}
```

Errors:

1. error: expected ']' before 'initWithName'
2. error: 'description' undeclared (first use in this function)

Thanks

Comment: Got a missing @ in the first warning, just noticed that.. Still no clue about the others though.

Comment: just put @ before "0" for first one , then for second one just put = between the description and [, then all is solved

Comment: Thanks, not a XML problem, just a need to go to sleep problem I guess. Thaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Expected "]" before initWithName" seems first error. You have missed assignent in that line.

```
NSXMLElement *description = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"description"];
```

Second error will go off automatically.